# YouTube embed API issue on IOS and Android

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

An issues popped up in the last few days with the YouTube embed API. The issue is that when you embed a video with the official API, it simply doesn't allow you to access to the API. When you try to access to the API, you got error message on the log (IOS) and if you try to play the video through the API the video blacks out. If you load it via the API, but you do not use the API, the user is able to play the video with tap.

The issue persist on the following browsers:

IOS 7 Safari on iPad and iPhone
IOS 7 Chrome on iPad and iPhone
Android 4 Chrome

(My play button uses the API to play the video and that produce the error)
JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/frdd8nvr/6/

Error message:

```
Unable to post message to https://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin http://fiddle.jshell.net.
postMessage[native code]:0
Jwww-widgetapi.js:26:357
Nwww-widgetapi.js:25
(anonymous function)[native code]:0
html5player.js:1201:97

Blocked a frame with origin "https://www.youtube.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://jsfiddle.net".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "http". Protocols must match.
```

Some debug info:

As I see the API create the iframe on the site. The src is sometime http and sometime https.

http://www.youtube.com/embed/ZPy9VCovVME?enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Ffiddle.jshell.net&autoplay=0&modestbranding=1&wmode=opaque&forceSSL=false

My test showed that most of the times YouTube servers simply LOCATION: https://... the request to the https url, but around 10% they served the http request with proper content.

I think somehow the issue related with the forced https, but I was not able to figure out the solution. 
Have you experienced the same? Do you have some kind of solution for this problem? Is it a YouTube bug?

My test code:

```
<div id="myvideo"></div>
<button id="play-button">Play</button>
```

JS:

```
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function () {
    var vars = {
        enablejsapi: 1,
        origin: window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host,
        autoplay: 0,
        modestbranding: 1,
        wmode: "opaque",
        forceSSL: false
    };

    if (+(navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') >= 0 && navigator.userAgent.search("Firefox") > -1)){
        vars.html5 = 1;
    }
            var playerobj = new YT.Player('myvideo', {
                videoId: 'ZPy9VCovVME',
                wmode: 'opaque',
                playerVars: vars,
                events: {
                    onReady: function(){
                        $('#play-button').on('click', function(){
                           playerobj.playVideo(); 
                        });
                        //playerobj.playVideo();
                    },
                    onStateChange: function(state){
                        switch(state.data){
                            case YT.PlayerState.PLAYING:
                                break;
                            //case YT.PlayerState.PAUSED:
                            case YT.PlayerState.ENDED:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: i'm not sure, maybe i don't understand something but your jsfiddle is working fine. You mean it's ONLY on ios ?

Comment: It doesn't work on IOS and Android and got the error on the console what I wrote. It seems for me it doesnt work when that iframe redirected to https, but I'm unable to find how to prevent that redirect... Maybe you got response from different server or different server software version running on that. I think it might be possible as sometimes I didn't get redirect to https..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I think this is a duplicate of the following question: [YouTube IFrame API play method doesn't work before touch on some Android tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607505/youtube-iframe-api-play-method-doesnt-work-before-touch-on-some-android-tablets)

I could reproduce the same problem on the [YouTube Player Demo page](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo).

The error

> Unable to post message to https://www.youtube.com. Recipient has origin http://fiddle.jshell.net.

is only occuring on your jsfiddle. On the demo page this error is not occuring, therefore your observed bug seems not to be related to the error logged in the console. I checked this with chrome on Android 4.4.4.

**Workaround**

I have a dirty workaround which works on chrome on Android 4.4.4 (Nexus5) and 4.1.2 (S2). I have no iOS Device to test this. The workaround works on my phones, because the video always starts the second time I click the play-button.

http://jsfiddle.net/kjwpwpx8/6/

I can always start the video on click-Events after the playVideo function was called once before. In my workaround I put two iframes on the page. One is hidden while the other one is visible. If the page is viewed by a mobile browser I call the playVideo function of the second video after the OnReady-Event. The video won't play as the browser blocks this.

Now when our play-button is pressed the first video becomes hidden and stopped and the second video becomes visible and the playVideo function is called again.

Here is the important code:

```
var playerOptions = {
    videoId: 'ZPy9VCovVME',
    wmode: 'opaque',
    playerVars: vars,
    events: {}
};

var playerobj1 = new YT.Player('myvideo1', playerOptions);
var playerobj2 = null;

playerOptions.events.onReady = function(){
    $('#play-button').on('click', function(){
        $("#videowrapper .video1wrapper").hide();
        playerobj1.stopVideo();

        $("#videowrapper .video2wrapper").show();
        playerobj2.playVideo();
    });

    if(isMobileBrowser)
        playerobj2.playVideo();
};

playerobj2 = new YT.Player('myvideo2', playerOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems for me this method which works for you on Android, doesn't work on IOS. But your explanation makes sense about the forced autoplay. We are unable to play the video with the API (even the fire event is a click). We should live with this restriction.