# Cordova / Phonegap for Android doesn't display youtube iFrame API

Tags: android, cordova, iframe, youtube, youtube-iframe-api

I'm facing the same issue displayed in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607505/youtube-iframe-api-play-method-doesnt-work-before-touch-on-some-android-tablets). I have the exact same symbol in the upper left corner as well. The only difference is, that I do not want to open the youtube video in a native browser, but in a cordova/phonegap app.

**My question now:**
Can I get it running by changing settings in cordova and disabling this restriction?

I hope somebody out there has a solution! Thank you in advance and if anything remained unclear please ask.

**EDIT:** I added the cordova.js to my external webpages and now the video is being display. BUT it directly skips to the end and shows other video suggestions. Any solutions for that?