# Youtube playback fails in webview due to "Cross origin requests"

Tags: android, webview, youtube

**Problem**

attempting to play video from within the webview (android 5.0) results in many "Cross origin requests" failures and video does not play.
HOWEVER, on Google Chrome, on the laptop, the HTML below makes the video plays perfectly fine !

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            html{width:100%;height:100%;}
            body{margin:0;width:100%;height:100%;background-color:black;}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='player'></div>
        <script> 
            var playerLoaded = false;
            var percentReported = 0;
            var percentCurrent = 0;
            var tag = document.createElement('script');
            tag.src = 'http://www.youtube.com/player_api'; 
            var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
            var player; 

            function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() { 
                playerLoaded = true;
                player = new YT.Player('player', { 
                    width:'100%', 
                    height:'100%', 
                    videoId:'CpaOh4poNms', 
                    playerVars: { playsinline: 1 }, 
                    events: { 
                        'onReady': onPlayerReady, 
                        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange, 
                        'onError': onPlayerError 
                    }
                }); 
            }

            function onPlayerReady(event) { 
                event.target.playVideo(); 
                setInterval(onPlayerTimeUpdate, 1000); 
            }

            function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
                } 
            }

            function onPlayerError(event) {
            }

            function onPlayerTimeUpdate() { 
                percentCurrent = Math.round(player.getCurrentTime() / player.getDuration() * 100); 
                if (percentCurrent > percentReported) { 
                     percentReported = percentCurrent; 
                }
            }

            setTimeout(function() { 
                if (!playerLoaded) { 
                } 
            }, 10000);
        </script> 
    </body>
</html>
```

**Errors**

> 01-15 11:21:42.410  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The
>   target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the
>   recipient window's origin ('http://www.youtube.com').", source:  (0)
>   01-15 11:21:42.898  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.899  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.899  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.901  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.901  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.911  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.914  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.914  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.917  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.921  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.922  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.923  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.926  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.928  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.928  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.929  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.930  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.931  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.931  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.931  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.935  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.939  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.940  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.943  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.946  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.947  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.948  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.958  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.961  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.962  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:42.964  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js.
>   Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.", source:
>   http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?playsinline=1&enablejsapi=1&origin=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com
>   (0) 01-15 11:21:43.246  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The
>   target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the
>   recipient window's origin ('http://www.youtube.com').", source:  (0)
>   01-15 11:21:43.305  21328-21328/com.my.android.app I/chromium﹕
>   [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'DOMWindow': The
>   target origin provided ('https://www.youtube.com') does not match the
>   recipient window's origin ('http://www.youtube.com').", source:  (0)

**How the Webview is initialized**

```
@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
public void setupWebView(WebView webView) {
    WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(false);
    webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(false);

    webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    webSettings.setSaveFormData(false);
    webSettings.setSupportZoom(false);
    webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(false);

    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCachePath("");

    webSettings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");

    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }

    webView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

}

private FrameLayout.LayoutParams COVER_SCREEN_GRAVITY_CENTER = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER);

    // this will allow the webview to play embedded video and full screen video
    mYoutubeVideoViewContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_youtube_video);
    mWebChromeClient = new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onShowCustomView(View view, WebChromeClient.CustomViewCallback callback)
        {
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);

            // if a view already exists then immediately terminate the new one
            if (mCustomView != null)
            {
                callback.onCustomViewHidden();
                return;
            }

            // Add the custom view to its container.
            mYoutubeVideoViewContainer.addView(view, COVER_SCREEN_GRAVITY_CENTER);
            mCustomView = view;
            mCustomViewCallback = callback;

            // hide main browser view
            mContentFlipper.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Finally show the custom view container.
            mYoutubeVideoViewContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            mYoutubeVideoViewContainer.bringToFront();
        }

        @Override
        public void onHideCustomView()
        {
            if (mCustomView == null) {
                return;
            }

            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

            // Hide the custom view.
            mCustomView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            // Remove the custom view from its container.
            mYoutubeVideoViewContainer.removeView(mCustomView);
            mCustomView = null;
            mYoutubeVideoViewContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mCustomViewCallback.onCustomViewHidden();

            // Show the content view.
            mContentFlipper.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    };
    mTargetWebView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
    mTargetWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

**How the HTML is loaded into the webview**

```
mTargetWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.youtube.com", youtubeHTML, "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

**Layout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fullscreen_youtube_video"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#FF000000">

        <ViewSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/contentFlipper"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/youtubeWebview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@android:color/white" />

        </ViewSwitcher>

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**What did I miss ?**

**PROGRESS...**

The only way I can get this crap to work on Android's (5.0) webview is to use the following HTML...

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?rel=0&autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

At least this will show the video player. This whole dynamic div-to-iframe crap is totally non-functional on Android: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

Comment: The `Getting Started` HTML fails the same way https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference   /facepalm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked out that `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady()` and `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady()` are **never** called on Android.

I wonder if this is on purpose to force people to switch to the [YouTube Library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) - which I would if the library didn't depend on the YouTube app.
I think there should be a "fat" and "thin" version of the library; the thin version depends on the youtube app and the fat version optionally requires it.

To make the video autoplay, I'm using the following code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27722504/550471
and trigger it from `onPageFinished()`

To load the HTML into the WebView, I'm using :
`webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://www.youtube.com", youtubeHTML, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8", null);`

The HTML consists of:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<iframe id="player" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/CpaOh4poNms?rel=0&origin=youtube.com" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: note... the Cross origin requests still show in logcat, but at least the video plays.

Comment: I got the same problem today...but I also noticed that your solution only works for some youtube videos. With this source link, I get a black screen http://www.youtube.com/embed/kPAgSisjpok?rel=0&autoplay=1 ... any ideas?