# android webview youtube embed video autoplay not working

Tags: java, android, webview, youtube, youtube-javascript-api

i am not able to autoplay my video please help in this.
my sdk version

```
  android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

i tried to put java script as specifed in code:

```
 public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()"); }
            });
```

i also try to append autoplay in URL but not working
`//webView.loadUrl("http://youtube.com/embed/oY2OxMpCUVY?autoplay=1");`

my web settings
`

```
customViewContainer = (FrameLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.customViewContainer);
        webView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.HelpView_Video);
        final GlobleClass globalVariable = (GlobleClass) GlobleClass.getContext();
        mWebViewClient = new HelpWebViewClient();
        webView.setWebViewClient(mWebViewClient);
        mWebChromeClient = new myWebChromeClient();
        webView.setWebChromeClient(mWebChromeClient);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            // autoplay when finished loading via javascript injection
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) { webView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()"); }
        });
//        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1) {
//            webView.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
//        }
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        //webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      //  webView.getSettings().setSaveFormData(true);
        //webView.loadUrl("http://youtube.com/embed/oY2OxMpCUVY?autoplay=1");
        webView.loadUrl(globalVariable.getHelpVideoUrl());
```

`

Comment: try this url `https://www.youtube.com/embed/oY2OxMpCUVY?autoplay=1` add www to url.

Comment: my video is working but not able to autoplay.i tried what you said.. not working..

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947758/how-to-auto-play-iframe-youtube-on-webview-android/76181022#76181022
This is my answer about it. I play with it well.

Answer (score 10):

Inspired by Orsi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44261758/1157458), I was able to mimic onClick() event on the center of the WebView that showed video player. This ultimately played the video automatically, or rather, without user's interaction.

```
private class AutoPlayVideoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        // mimic onClick() event on the center of the WebView
        long delta = 100;
        long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        float x = view.getLeft() + (view.getWidth()/2);
        float y = view.getTop() + (view.getHeight()/2);

        MotionEvent tapDownEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, downTime + delta, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
        tapDownEvent.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER);
        MotionEvent tapUpEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, downTime + delta + 2, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
        tapUpEvent.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER);

        view.dispatchTouchEvent(tapDownEvent);
        view.dispatchTouchEvent(tapUpEvent);
    }
}
```

Somewhere,

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new AutoPlayVideoWebViewClient());
```

Answer (score 4):

First used below code :

```
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

After that used below method for loading:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://www.youtube.com/", HTML.replace("CUSTOM_ID","YOUR_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_ID"), "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

In HTML string pass below Code with YouTube API (Replaced your YouTube video ID)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            background-color: #000000;
            overflow: hidden;
            position: fixed;
        }
    </style>
<body>

 <div id="player"></div>
<script>
       var tag = document.createElement('script');
       tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
       var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
       firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
       var player;
       function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
            player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    height: '100%',
                    width: '100%',
                    videoId: 'CUSTOM_ID',
                    events: {
                       'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                       'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                  },
                  playerVars: {
                        'autoplay': 0,
                        'showinfo': 1,
                        'controls': 1
                                }
                            });
                        }
                        function onPlayerReady(event) {
                            event.target.playVideo();

                        }

                        var done = false;
                        function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
                            if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
                                done = true;
                            }
                        }
                        function stopVideo() {
                            player.stopVideo();
                        }
                    </script> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thx. It really works to me. The 'playerVars' seems to be unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I made it..
You need to use this API to play the video on "OnReady" event:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started

Load the page that contains the code from this example.

And make sure you have

```
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

(API 16+)

Comment: Cool. So Google provided a guide-preference. Never  know that.

Answer (score 2):

The C# version of the code posted by bonnyz in his answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607505/youtube-iframe-api-play-method-doesnt-work-before-touch-on-some-android-tablets/27722504#27722504). Just in case someone needs it for Xamarin :) I tested it and it works. It was the only solution I have found to autoplay youtube videos in a webview.

```
public class MyWebViewClient : WebViewClient
{
    WebView webView;
    MotionEvent motionEvent, motionEvent2;

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        long delta = 100;
        long downTime = SystemClock.UptimeMillis();
        float x = view.Left + view.Width / 2;
        float y = view.Top + view.Height / 2;
        webView = view;

        motionEvent = MotionEvent.Obtain(downTime, downTime + delta, MotionEventActions.Down, x, y, 0);
        motionEvent2 = MotionEvent.Obtain(downTime + delta + 1, downTime + delta * 2, MotionEventActions.Up, x, y, 0);

        int delay = 100;
        view.PostDelayed(TapDown, delay);
        delay += 100;
        view.PostDelayed(TapUp, delay);
    }


    private void TapDown()
    {
        webView.DispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    private void TapUp()
    {
        webView.DispatchTouchEvent(motionEvent2); 
    }
}
```

To use it:

```
webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
```

Comment: thanks to this answer, I manged to do it in Java with some critical tweaks tho. See, https://stackoverflow.com/a/45655979/1157458

Answer (score 0):

You can't do autoplay with JavaScript on the webview.
In order to enhance user experience , WebKit disables the option to autoplay videos on mobile browsers.

Comment: how can i enable that option?

Answer (score 0):

The **autoplay issue is a known problem**, please take a look to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607505/youtube-iframe-api-play-method-doesnt-work-before-touch-on-some-android-tablets/27722504#27722504).

Answer (score 0):

Adding value @Dhunju_likes_to_Learn's answer. Handling the back button pressed in onResume, onPause and onDestroy methods as suggested by [Thiago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37337884/2795035)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle arg0) {
    super.onCreate(arg0);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
    // Call the AutoPlayVideoWebViewClient class in onCreate method
    myWebView.setWebViewClient(new AutoPlayVideoWebViewClient());
}
```

Write a private

```
private class AutoPlayVideoWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    // mimic onClick() event on the center of the WebView
    long delta = 100;
    long downTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    float x = view.getLeft() + (view.getWidth()/2);
    float y = view.getTop() + (view.getHeight()/2);

    MotionEvent tapDownEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, downTime + delta, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
    tapDownEvent.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER);
    MotionEvent tapUpEvent = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, downTime + delta + 2, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0);
    tapUpEvent.setSource(InputDevice.SOURCE_CLASS_POINTER);

    view.dispatchTouchEvent(tapDownEvent);
    view.dispatchTouchEvent(tapUpEvent);
}
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    myWebView.onPause();
    myWebView.pauseTimers();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override 
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    myWebView.resumeTimers();
    myWebView.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    myWebView.destroy();
    myWebView = null;
    super.onDestroy();
}
```